# How can session be passed along between calls in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

In our rails 3.2 app, there is call from a helper method `search_helper` to a method `access_right` in another module. Here is the code in `search_helper` .

```
models = Authentify::UserPrivilegeHelper.access_right('index', params[:controller])
```

Before calling `access_right`, the `session[:user_right]` is defined and available in `search_helper`. However in `access_right`, the `seesion[:user_right]` becomes undefined and lost. How can the session be passed along from `search_helper` into `access_right` without being lost?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435452/visibility-of-session-variable-in-rails) and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model) for advanced sessions usage